# How to implement tintcolor behaviour for UIButtonTypeCustom

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm using a custom button type since I need the touch areas to be non-rectangular so am using a class called `OBShapedButton` which I shamelessly found online. However, I also want to color these buttons to match the player's color.

When talking about `UIButton` and `tintcolor`, [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uibutton_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/tintColor) say

> This property has no default effect for buttons with type
>   `UIButtonTypeCustom`. For custom buttons, you must implement any
>   behavior related to `tintColor` yourself.

So how would I go about implementing this behaviour myself?

Answer (score 0):

you could create an array of colors using UIColor within your class then access them individually have you tried it that way?

ok as an example something like this

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

ideally can you post your class code aswell

Comment: Sure, storing a list of colors isn't the problem, it's that setting `tintcolor` on a custom button type is not supported. I'm trying to work out how to implement the same standard tinting behaviour seen on other button types.